# Google Spreadsheet - SUMIF Date Range

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet, in which I want to sum the table if records are older than 1 year.

I have inventory in 1 sheet with purchase date and other stuff, and in 2nd sheet, I want to sum the inventory which is older than 1 year (inspection date is a separate column in 2nd sheet)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Spreadsheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cRLTlwRfs2LaqoRyyHF3VcAEjKWWOu5XwBwApXLqJuo/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sum B column older than year:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A, ">"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1, MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())), B2:B)
```

[image: 0]

---

sum stuff between two dates:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B, 
 A2:A, ">"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1, MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())), 
 A2:A, "<="&TODAY())
```

[image: 0]